# Regex java finding string from txtfile

Tags: java, regex

```
exp("^[a[k][t][l]]{6}$");
exp("^(bEt).*(oc)$");
exp("^(bEt)$");
exp("^(a).*");
exp("bEt(oc)*");
exp("^(bEt).*");
```

**exp("[baba[bebe][bibi][bobo][bubu][fafa][fefe][fofo][fufu]");**

I am wondering how to find any of the strings "baba", "bebe", "bibi", "bobo", "bubu",
"fafa", "fefe", "", "fofo" eller "fufu" from a txtfile. I´ve searched for answears but cant find them. In my opinion the last line would be the solution, but its not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[]` creates a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html), `|` is the `or` operator. Try

```
exp("baba|bebe|bibi|bobo|bubu|fafa|fefe|fofo|fufu");
```

This can be shortened too, one alternative way to write it is

```
exp("bibi|([bf][aeou])\\1");
```

I strongly recommend a tour through the complete [regex section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) of the Java Tutorials.